# The dividend yield of AMC is reported differently on different financial info websites. How do I know which is correct?

Tags: financial-literacy, dividends, yahoo-finance, google-finance

Google Finance says the dividend yield of AMC is 2.68%, Yahoo Finance says it's "N/A", Marketwatch says it's "0.00%", and Robinhood says it's 17.95%. I'm very surprised to see that all these difference financial information sources disagree on this. I would have expected them to all report the same number. Is this kind of disagreement on the facts between different financial info sources normal? And how do I know what the true dividend yield is for AMC?

Comment: `N/A` certainly means "Not Available"; Yahoo hasn't updated the site yet.  Marketwatch's `0.00%` probably means the same thing.  Robinhood looks... broken.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the past 5 quarters the dividend has been 20 cents per quarter.  So based on a price of $4.46, the yield would be 17.95% which is what Robinhood says (raspberry sound!).

However, the dividend has been cut and it will be 3 cents on the next ex-dividend date of Mar 6th.  So that means that based on the new dividend of 3 cents, the yield is 2.69%.  Based on that, Google Finance gets the chicken dinner.

Comment: I'm surprised they kept issuing such high dividends last year.

Comment: I'd agree with you on that.  Even though it makes sense to cut the dividend, sometimes, companies try to avoid cutting the dividend because that can lead to further share price deterioration.

Comment: @BobBaerker where are you finding that the price of M is 4.46? I'm seeing $14.28 today on google finance. If google finance has the right stock price and we use the new dividend of 3 cents to calculate the yield, then 0.03/14.28=0.0021=0.21%, which doesn't match any of the finance sites.

Comment: @STN - OK, you've confused me.  Why are you now asking about M which is Macy's when the original question was about AMC?

Comment: @BobBaerker I got my wires crossed, sorry. It all makes sense now, please disregard the previous comment about M. Thanks for answering!

Comment: AMC is  trading above $14.28 today.  Maybe your wires really weren't crossed ;->).  I hope you own some shares.